# Chapter in header

Tags: header-footer

iam using the book class to write my thesis, sections of each chapters are displayed with the fancy package in the header. However, my conclusion has no sections but spans over several pages. At the moment above the horizontal line hence there is only white space. How could I display in this chapter the chapter in the header?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  To add the chapter name to the "empty" running head, insert a line after the `\chapter` line: `\markboth{<chapter name>}{<chapter name>}`.  I'm sure this has been answered before, but haven't found a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. Im loading the chapter in via \input command. If I do what you say, I have only on the last page an entry, but not on other pages of the conclusion where I would like to have it. Any ideas?

Comment: Put the `\markboth` line inside the file your are `\input`ting.  That's a guess, since without code giving context, there's nothing to test.

Comment: With most document classes, \chapter calls \chaptermark to perform the \markboth.  All you have to do is \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{...} where #1 contain the chapter title.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks a lot, it worked. Im not sure, but maybe the distance between the number and the text is a bit smaller than in the cases where the text is automatically put into the header based on my preamble input. It is not a big thing, but how could one adjust that distance?

Comment: `book.cls` defines the `\chaptermark` with `\thechapter. \ `, that is, an extra space after the period.  You can do that to match the wider space.